# Not able to get weekday from Date

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate

I am getting a date from coredata and trying to get the weekday of that date.I tried the following code but its not working.

```
    NSDateFormatter *weekDayFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [weekDayFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEEE"];
    NSDate *weekDay = [results valueForKey:@"date"];
    NSLog(@"%@",weekDay);//This log is working.
    NSString *weekDayString = [weekDayFormatter stringFromDate:weekDay];
    NSLog(@"%@",weekDayString); //This log is displaying null.
    NSLog(@"%@ is spent on %@",[results valueForKey:@"amount"],weekDayString);
```

It is working if i am using `[NSDate date]` instead of `[results valueForKey:@"date"]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

NSDateComponents *weekdayComponents =[gregorian components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit fromDate:dateOfInterest];

NSInteger weekday = [weekdayComponents weekday];
// weekday 1 = Sunday for Gregorian calendar

[gregorian release];
```

Comment: Tried this but i got an exception .. 2013-03-13 17:15:24.417 XpenseTracker[14562:c07] -[__NSArrayI timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xfa56460
2013-03-13 17:15:24.418 XpenseTracker[14562:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xfa56460'

Comment: You are calling timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate on an NSArray instead of NSDate . Thats why exception is coming.

Comment: I dont understand.Can you please tell me how to resolve it?.Is it because i used a predicate?

Comment: where are you using this function : timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate ??

Comment: what is the fromDate (2nd parameter) value you have given ?

Comment: its [results valueForKey:@"date"]

Comment: Thanks Arun.I figured it out. I am trying to access an array instead of an individual element.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a `NSCalendar` to extract `NSDateComponents` from your `NSDate`.

Answer (score 0):

I think `[results valueForKey:@"date"]` gives NSString type object. Check it once. If it is true convert it to NSDate.

Case 1:

```
 NSDateFormatter *weekDayFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [weekDayFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEEE"];
    NSDate *weekDay = @"2013-03-13 11:06:55 +0000";//here warning is there...
    NSLog(@"%@",weekDay);//This log is working.
    NSString *weekDayString = [weekDayFormatter stringFromDate:weekDay];
    NSLog(@"%@",weekDayString); //It gives NULL...
```

In this case, answer is null.

Case 2:

```
NSDateFormatter *weekDayFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [weekDayFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEEE"];
    NSDate *weekDay = [NSDate date];
    NSLog(@"%@",weekDay);//This log is working.
    NSString *weekDayString = [weekDayFormatter stringFromDate:weekDay];
    NSLog(@"%@",weekDayString); //It gives results...
```

In this case, answer is yourResult.

Comment: NSDateFormatter *weekDayFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [weekDayFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z"];
    NSDate *weekDayDate = [weekDayFormatter dateFromString:[results valueForKey:@"date"]];
    [weekDayFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEEE"];
    NSString *weekDayString = [weekDayFormatter stringFromDate:weekDayDate];
    NSLog(@"%@",weekDayString); is not working

Comment: 2013-03-13 17:05:46.216 XpenseTracker[14249:c07] -[__NSArrayI length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x89db720
2013-03-13 17:05:46.217 XpenseTracker[14249:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x89db720'

Comment: What is the return type of [results valueForKey:@"date"] and What is NSLog of [results valueForKey:@"date"]?

Comment: return type is date. and the log is 2013-03-13 17:13:31.830 XpenseTracker[14477:c07] (
    "2013-03-12 13:41:05 +0000",
    "2013-03-13 07:47:56 +0000"
)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the same date format which you received from [results valueforKey:@"date"]. Thereafter you try to format the date as how you need.

```
NSDateFormatter *weekDayFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[weekDayFormatter setDateFormat:SAME FORMAT YOU RECEIVING];
NSDate *weekDay = [weekDayFormatter dateFromString:[results valueForKey@"date"]];   
NSLog(@"%@",weekDay);
[weekDayFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEEE"];
NSString *weekDayString = [weekDayFormatter stringFromDate:weekDay];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Your date as a string
NSString *yourDate = @"02-09-2011 20:54:18";    //  [results valueForKey:@"date"]

// Prepare an NSDateFormatter to convert to and from the string representation
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

// set format as your Date string (Eg. dd/MM/yyyy for 25/12/2012)
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"];

// Parse the string representation of the date
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:yourDate];

NSDateFormatter* theDateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[theDateFormatter setFormatterBehavior:NSDateFormatterBehavior10_4];
[theDateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEEE"];
NSString *weekDay =  [theDateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
NSLog(@"%@",weekDay);
```

Comment: got this exception 2013-03-13 17:10:07.095 XpenseTracker[14399:c07] -[__NSArrayI length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xfa97e70
2013-03-13 17:10:07.096 XpenseTracker[14399:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xfa97e70'

Comment: I have tested this code, its perfect, and your exception is due to some array in your program, please find and fix it.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];

NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

NSDateComponents *todayComponents = [gregorian components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit fromDate:today];

NSLog(@"weekday = %d",[todayComponents weekday]);
```